# Alternate to Marketing Cloud Sandbox?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sandbox

I hope you are all aware of the below recent update form Salesforce!

[END of Life of MC Sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_october_2019_eol_sandbox_accounts.htm&type=5)

Please share your advise to achieve the below,

1) As per my understating the BEST PRACTICE would be to create Business Unit and use it as a Testing environment/Sand box! - Please correct me if I am wrong.

2) How would I move my contents[Emails, images, Triggersend Defns. etc] from Sandbox to this new BU in Production.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted, so others can easily see this has been resolved. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkusSlabina sure. And thanks... Also I wanted to make a note the MOST of the migration work needs to be done MANUALLY writing custom API codes, as I installed and checked DEPLOYMENT MANAGER, which DOES NOT support DE and other assets like images, emails to be exported :( ... Anyhow thanks for your advice (y)

Comment: There was a session at Dreamforce this year where the rough roadmap of deployment manager was presented and data extensions should work within the very near future as it already works in the background. There are a lot of nice features planned (resolving dependencies and migrating dependent assets, etc.). However it is just a Salesforce Labs project and not (yet?) part of Marketing Cloud itself. They also make use of internal APIs which aren't exposed to customers/partners so there is a lot of stuff possible in the future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, if a sandbox/testing environment is necessary, using a dedicated business unit for that purpose is the best practice. Just make sure, that you take all the necessary measures, to keep the data separate (eg. using subscriber filters, so your sandbox-BU subscribers don't show up in other BUs' view of all subscriber list), but be aware, that no 100% separation is currently possible. For example contacts of your sandbox BU will always show up in Contact Builder under "All Contacts".

To move your assets, you could either use [Deployment Manger](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_deployment_manager.htm&type=5) or the API (most possibly a mix is necessary).

**Further resources:**

- [Deployment Manger - Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_deployment_manager.htm&type=5)
- [Deployment Manager - AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FvMviUAF)
- [Marketing Cloud APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm)